# JHipster custom component GET http://localhost:9000/api/account 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: jhipster

I have created JHipster monolithic application.

Using jdl-studio i have created entities.

After that i have created my own module with submodules.

In app.module.ts i have created app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

in app-routing module routing to other modules is defined like this

```
const routes: Routes = [


    {
        path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => {
            (require as any).ensure([], require => {
                resolve(require('./pages/pages.module').PagesModule);
            })
        })
    },


    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages'},
```

Routing works just fine, i have no problems at all.

But when i try calling entities services from custom components which are defined inside this custom modules, i receive error

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/account 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I am able to login without problems, i am able to access Principal service inside header, but when i try calling any of services from inside custom components i receive this error

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its difficult to answer it without seeing more code. maybe the services are being recreated for those components and not shared from root context. Singleton services should be provided only once per application. I would suggest you to look closely how the generated code is and follow the same fr your custom modules. Also might be a problem with lazy loading. See if it works wiothout lazy loading first

Comment: Thanks very much for a reply.
It is definitely some problem with lazy loading.
I have solved problem with entities services,
but i am not able at all to solve problem with Principal and Translate services.

Recomendation is to use shared module with lazy loading, but it is not working at all in my case.

Do you have any advice how to implement shared module?

Comment: Again I cant recommend anything without seeing code, so I suggest you look at existing lazy loaded admin modules to see how its done

Comment: I have found the solution.
The problem was definitely with lazy-loading, to be precise with the way services are loaded inside lazy-loaded modules.
The solution was to create shared-module.

Thanks again, your comments were very helpful to me